# Node start VLC Player with child_process

Tags: node.js, vlc, child-process

I have a POST function in which I am trying to start VLC player using the child_process. I am using the latest Raspbian version.

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
    let spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    let vlc = spawn('vlc');
    vlc.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log(data.toString());
    });
    vlc.on('exit', function(code){
        console.log('Exit code: ' + code);
    });
    res.send({success: true})
});
```

After triggering the request, I get this message:

> VLC is not supposed to be run as root. Sorry. If you need to use
>   real-time priorities and/or privileged TCP ports you can use
>   vlc-wrapper (make sure it is Set-UID root and cannot be run by
>   non-trusted users first).

Since VLC cannot be run as root, I added the UID argument to the vlc start script, and it now looks like this:

```
let vlc = spawn('vlc' ,{uid: 1000});
```

Where UID: 1000 is the ID of the user I always use.

After triggering the request, I get another message in the log:

> [016f9960] main libvlc error: cannot open config file
>   (/root/.config/vlc/vlcrc): Permission denied
>
> Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
>
> [01762eb0] vlcpulse audio output error: PulseAudio server connection
>   failure: Connection refused
>
> [0176bde8] dbus interface error: Failed to connect to the D-Bus
>   session daemon: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY
>   for X11
>
> [0176bde8] main interface error: no suitable interface module
>   [016f9960] main libvlc error: interface "dbus,none" initialization
>   failed
>
> [0176c7a8] main interface error: no suitable interface module
>   [016f9960] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none"
>   initialization failed
>
> [016f9960] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use
>   'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
>
> error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
>
> [0176c7a8] skins2 interface error: cannot initialize OSFactory
>
> [017614e0] main playlist: playlist is empty
>
> [0176c7a8] [cli] lua interface: Listening on host "*console".

The player doesn't run. But if I run the same command via ssh, it will run. What could cause node from not running it?

Comment: Have you tried to launch your app as a non root user ?

Comment: @TGrif Yes when I added UID argument, it's a non root user

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my server was running using

> **nodemon**

I literally tried everything, and then when I was about to give up, I accidentally started server the normal way using **node** command. The VLC is starting without any errors. I didn't have to pass any user ID in arguments. It works fine just like this:

```
let spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
let vlc = spawn('vlc');
```

I'm really curious why nodemon could cause such a behaviour.